# Can an Iranian journal accept submissions from Israeli researchers?

Tags: journals, international, iran, israel

I am an Israeli researcher and am planning to submit my paper soon.

I noticed that an Iranian journal¹ has suitable editors and am considering submitting there. I wonder whether such a journal might accept my submission.

Are there are any general rules prohibiting Iranian journals from accepting submissions from Israelis?

---

<sup>¹ It is a journal of an Iranian society, published in Iran, and almost of all of its editors (but not all of them) are Iranians.</sup>

Comment: Iranian authors (based in Iran) have published in the Israel Journal of Mathematics. So it's not entirely unheard of.

Comment: A possibly relevant data point: Note the location of the authors of https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.01574 (and two more papers by the same authors).

Answer (score 11):

As it is mentioned by others, it does not hurt if you contact the editor and simply ask. However, as an Iranian, **I am nearly sure that you are not allowed to do so**. It does not work to think logically about the question. Iran and Israel relation is in such a bad state that it effects all aspects of the society. I think that it creates a lot of unwanted problems for the editors that committed to it if they accept to review or publish your paper. 
If you are curious about publishing in that journal, you may need to use other affiliations of yourself (e.g. IEEE member) and a non country-specific email domain, as in this case they probably do not notice to your nationality.

Comment: So you're saying it's essentially a question of appearances? I mean, after all, it's pretty easy to figure out where a certain academic is from, given his/her name.

Comment: *after all, it's pretty easy to figure out where a certain academic is from, given his/her name.* There are lots of counterexamples to this claim...

Comment: yeah. By the way, it is always a risk of being detected. I said that by changing your affiliation or email address you may decrease the chance of a direct rejection.

Answer (score 7):

You should simply **ask the journal's editors**.

There is absolutely no problem or danger, to you or to them, in doing that, as Israelis and Iranians get in contact as academics all the time, all over the world.

(I would also bet an acceptance would be possible but that's pure speculation.)

Comment: In fact I agree with this answer and upvoted it.  However, depending on the kind of journal I might consider emailing to the personal (academic) email address of one or more members of the board rather than a journal email address.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: I think that's not necessary, but I suppose there's no harm in doing that.

Answer (score 4):

The journal will not explicitly prohibit your paper based on your nationality as the academics in Iran, just like any other country, will judge the paper based on scientific merit. However, many government organizations are strictly against such behavior and will take action if they found out such a paper was published. These actions include forcing the journal to retract a paper or punishing the editor for accepting it in the fist place. This situation might sway the editorial board to reject the paper, just to avoid such troubles. However, if your nationality is not obvious based on your affiliation, I wouldn't expect any issues (even if the editorial board knows you're from Israel).